# Problem in a number guessing program's while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Yython programming. I create a simple program with random module, that ask for number, and person need to guess an number. I got problem with getting the answer. Even if I give the correct answer, program isn't stopping, here's the code:

```
import random

run = True
answer = random.randint(1,9)
guess = input("Give me an number in 1 to 9: ")
print(answer)

while run:
    if guess == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you won!\n" * 5)
        run = False
    else:
        guess = input("Try again: ")
        print(answer)
```

The `print(answer)` line is for me to know what is the answer, and even if I write it down, program isn't stopping.

Comment: change to `guess = int(input("Give me an number in 1 to 9: "))`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python input tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  You're comparing an integer to a string; those can never be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`answer` is always an integer:

```
answer = random.randint(1,9)
```

and `guess` is always a string:

```
guess = input("Give me an number in 1 to 9: ")
```

thus they can never be equal.

You need to conver the inputted string to an integer:

```
guess = int(input("Give me an number in 1 to 9: "))
```

Or better yet, convert the generated random number to a string, to avoid the issue of the program crashing when the user inputs a non digit:

```
answer = str(random.randint(1,9))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, embarrased didn't realise that by myself :D int() worked here

Comment: It would be better to convert the number to a string to avoid crashing without try and except

Comment: @Hippolippo True, edited that in :)

Answer (score 1):

The random function will return an integer and the input function will return a string in python, `"1"` is not equal to `1`. To be able to check if the input is the same, convert the random number to a string by doing `guess == str(answer)` instead